# From Python List I want to print first element to second element,third element to fourth element

Tags: python-3.x

This is my list-

```
fam = ['mom',54,'dad',56,'sister',25,'myself',29]
```

This shows family member and next to it it their respective age. i want to print like -

```
Age of mom is : 54
Age of dad is : 56
```

Like that. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: It is highly recommended that, in your future questions, you show what you have done/attempted so far and the challenges you faced.

Comment: Sure. I am a new here. Will surely post my details going forward. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also remember to put closure to your questions by marking an answer of your choice as accepted. You are welcome to wait for more answers to arrive so you have more choices to select from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
fam = ['mom',54,'dad',56,'sister',25,'myself',29]

for x in range(0, len(fam), 2):
    print('Age of {} is : {}'.format(fam[x], fam[x+1]))
```

**Result**

```
Age of mom is : 54
Age of dad is : 56
Age of sister is : 25
Age of myself is : 29
```

**Explanation**

Starting index of your list is 0. The item you are on is the person and the next item is their age. Once you print that, hop 2 spots and continue the process.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly optimized way of storing your data is in a dictionary rather than a list.
So if your data is in a list like `['mom',54,'dad',56,'sister',25,'myself',29]`, a dictionary will look like.

```
{'mom':54,
'dad':56,
'sister':25,
'myself':29
}
```

Then to get the data you want, you would just iterate over the dictionary, this avoids you to use indexing to differentiate between name and age.

```
family = {'mom':54,
'dad':56,
'sister':25,
'myself':29
}

#Iterate over the dictionary using dict.items()
for name, age in family.items():
    print('Age of {} is : {}'.format(name, age))
```

And the output will be

```
Age of mom is : 54
Age of dad is : 56
Age of sister is : 25
Age of myself is : 29
```